# Block Pip from implicitly installing packages

Tags: pip

Is there anyway to instruct pip not to install any packages unless they are explicitly specific on the command line or in the requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-no-deps:

```
pip install --no-deps
```

Don’t install package dependencies.